# Extract user details from PFUser not working: Key "username" has no data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform

I have a Parse.com class called Messages, where I have 3 columns:

```
- fromUser - Pointer<_User>
- toUser - Pointer<_User>
```

In my UITableView I'm retrieving all objects in the Messages-class where toUser is equal to PFUser currentUser. I'm getting this error when I try to assign a label to the fromUser:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Key "username" has no data.  Call fetchIfNeeded before getting its value.
```

Here's how I do the query:

```
- (void)retriveMessages {
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Messages"];
    [query whereKey:@"toUser" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
    [query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
    query.limit = 1000;
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, error.userInfo);
        } else {

            // Found messages!
            self.messages = objects;
            [self.tableView reloadData];
            [_message fetchIfNeeded];
            NSLog(@"Retrived %d messages", self.messages.count);
        }
    }];
}
```

And this is how I try to assign the label to the fromUser-row, which is a pointer to the User class:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    MessageCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MessageCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    _message = [_messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [_message fetchIfNeeded];

    PFUser *user = (PFUser*)[_message objectForKey:@"fromUser"];
    NSString *nameString = [user username];
    cell.nameLabel.text = nameString;

    cell.feedDelegate = self;

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to access attributes of the pointed-to @"fromUser", you must eagerly fetch it in the find.  Add this to the query:

```
[query includeKey:@"fromUser"];
```